# Stored Procedure which accepts parameters from users and displays result

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database which has two tables. One table contains the information of all the servers in my environment with feilds like server_name, db_name, application, Pri_dba etc. and the other table has contact info for all the DBA like thier phone numbers emails etc. I want to write a stored procedure which accepts 3 values from users that is Server name , Database & Application. It should then uniquely identify the Primary DBA based on this info and display all the contact information for that DBA.
I figured I can identify the primary DBA from table 1 and display the result from table 2.
This might be a very easy task but I am a new DBA so Can any one please help.

Comment: Have you tried to write the query yet of the information you want to pull?

Comment: That's nice. What have you tried?

Comment: All I have got till now is " Select * from contact_info a where a.dba = b.pri_dba" b being the first table... but i dont knw hw to reference it in my querry...

Comment: All I have got till now is: 
create procedure contacts 
srv_name varchar(500)
db_name varchar(200)
application varchar(300)
as 
begin 

Declare pri varchar(500) 
pri = (select pri_dba from db_details where 
       server_name = srv_name and db_name = db_name and app_name = application)

select * from dba_contact where dba_name = pri

go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this. Obviously you will need to substitute correwct column names...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE IdentifyDBA (@Srv VARCHAR(20), @DB VARCHAR(20), App VARCHAR(20))
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT B.*
    FROM DBATable B
    INNER JOIN AssetTbl A
        ON A.dba = B.Pri_DBA
    WHERE A.ServerName = @Srv
    AND A.DBName = @DB
    AND A.AppName = @App
END

EXEC IdentifyDBA 'ServerA', 'DatabaseA', 'ApplicationA'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know your data structure it's hard to give something exact, but you should be able to modify this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetDBAForServer (@ServerName varchar(100), @DatabaseName varchar(100), @ApplicationName varchar(100))
AS 
SELECT di.*
FROM server_info si
INNER JOIN dba_info di on si.pri_dba = di.id
WHERE si.name = @ServerName
  AND si.dbname = @DatabaseName
  AND si.appname = @ApplicationName
```

Then you could call this as:

```
EXEC GetDBAForServer 'Server1', 'Database3', 'Application2'
```

Hope this helps!